# Ecw file to something else

Tags: qgis, ecw

I have an ecw aerial map of part of Denmark, I need to import that aerial map into another program, and to do that I need to change the format to a picture. The georeference doesn't matter.

I have been trying to save the file as a geotiff, but the size is enormous, so I want to know if there is any other way to save the ecw to a file that can be opened in fx photoshop.

When using the "convert format" to jpeg, the program argues that the number of bands is not supported.

any good ideas how to change the format without having files that are 50GB, still keep the high resolution, and where it is possible to open the new picture in fx photoshop?

Comment: Create GeoTIFF as tiled, with internal JPEG compression and you should get about the same file size as with ECW.

Comment: ECW is a licensed compression because it is quite good. If there would be another open alternative no one would pay the money for it. What user30184 wrote will probably bring down the file size in the same regions. But you need to carefully check the quality and performance. Shouldn´t there be a plugin for photoshop?

Comment: There is no doubt that ECW is good, the problem is that I need to map the picture on a surface in a 3D program, and unfortunately is it only possible to use giff, jepg, png and so on :)